# Unable to do static import

Tags: java, import, static-import

//interface1.java

```
package package1;
   public interface interface1 {
      static final int a =10;
   }
```

//StaticImportTest.java

```
 import static package1.*;         //import package1.*; works

   class StaticImportTest {
      public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(a);     //System.out.println(interface1.a) works
      }
   }
```

when i am replacing the word "import static" with only "import" and using System.out.println(interface1.a) it works, but not sure why its not working in its current form.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. Why are you trying to make this peculiar construction work?

Comment: just experimenting with the use of static import and got stuck

Comment: Instead of experimenting, read a Tutorial.  For a static import, the qualified name before the `.*` must be a qualified class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your static import to work the way you intended it would have to be
`import static package1.interface1.*` or `import static package1.interface1.a`
A static import imports public static members of a class either all with * or a specific one like for example `a`.
A import on the other hand imports a package or specific classes from a package.

Your `import static package1.*` would try to import all members from the class `package1` in the root package.

Making it a normal import and accessing `a` via `interface1.a` works because the import imports all classes from the `package1` including `interface1`, therefor you can access `a` via the `interface1` class.